# Removing a row based on its content

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to write a code that removes an observation based on its content. The idea is, every observation must have a review after Initial/ Pre-Initial.

My data frame looks like this:

```
ID  Type            Registered
P40 Pre-Initial     Yes
P40 Review  
P40 Review  
P42 Initial         Yes
P43 Initial         Yes
P43 Review  
P44 Pre-Initial     Yes
P44 Review
```

My dput code:

```
tt <- structure(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P40", "P42", "P43", "P43",
                            "P44", "P44"),Type = c("Pre-Initial", "Review", "Review", "Initial", "Initial", "Review", "Pre-Initial", "Review"),
                     Registered = c("Yes", "", "", "Yes", "Yes", "", "Yes", "")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

This waht i want to achieve:

```
ID  Type            Registered
P40 Pre-Initial     Yes
P40 Review  
P40 Review  
P43 Initial         Yes
P43 Review  
P44 Pre-Initial     Yes
P44 Review
```

This is the code I have tried so far, but its not working.

```
 tt %>% group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(which(Registered == "Yes" & any(Type != "Review")))
)
```

Comment: You seem to have multiple related problems which would be vastly simplified if you changed the format your data is currently in. The fundamental issue is that your data has empty cells, because the `Registered` value is not recorded for `Review`s. Is this correct? If so, the table you chose isn’t a good way of representing your data. I recommend you read the advice by Karl Broman about [how to structure tabular data](https://kbroman.org/dataorg/pages/rectangle.html). It will probably make solving your problems much simpler.

Comment: Try `tt %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() > 1 & any(Type == 'Review'))`

Comment: @ Sotos, thanx that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to simply keep groups with more than 1 rows and the entry `Review`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

tt %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 filter(n() > 1 & any(Type == 'Review'))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Every observation must have a review after Initial/ Pre-Initial.

Get all indices where `Type == "Review"` and extract it's last index and compare it with index of `c("Pre-Initial", "Initial")` and select group if `any` of the index is greater.

```
library(dplyr)

tt %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(tail(which(Type == "Review"), 1) > 
             which(Type %in% c("Pre-Initial", "Initial"))))

#  ID    Type        Registered
#  <chr> <chr>       <chr>     
#1 P40   Pre-Initial Yes       
#2 P40   Review      ""        
#3 P40   Review      ""        
#4 P43   Initial     Yes       
#5 P43   Review      ""        
#6 P44   Pre-Initial Yes       
#7 P44   Review      ""
```